# Magento Inner pages redirect to unrelated page

Tags: php, magento

i have a magento multi store when i load home page for first time it works ok but if i directly open inner page then it redirects me to some unrelated URL if i open the inner page in incognito window then it redirects me link is

[Link](http://production.technology-architects.com/brand24/index.php/brands/addidas/adidas-originals.html)

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Try Go to System -> Configuration -> Web -> Secure

Check if "Base Link URL" is set with "https".

Check that "Use Secure URLs in Frontend" is set to Yes.